# Can't update database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm currently using Codeigniter. I'm trying to update my database by this way:

```
function index($email) //function wchich will reset the password in the database;
{
    $new_password = random_string('alnum', 16); //generate random password
    $this-> db->set('password', md5($new_password), FALSE);
    $this-> db->where('email', $email);
    $this-> db->update('CI_TEST');

    echo ''. $this->db->last_query();
    exit();
    echo '-> '. $this->db->affected_rows(). '</br>';
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return ($new_password);
}
```

I learnt how to update the database on the Codeigniter website.
Otherwise my browser doesn't throw me any error, however I tried to display the last query using the appropriate function as below, and it give me exactly what I would like to do, more precisely:

> UPDATE `ci_test` SET password = 5167ec0e9c076c2c45550ee7581c07f6 WHERE
>   `email` = 'test@gmail.com'

But, when I use $this->db->affected_row() function to know if the database was modify successfully, it just give me

```
-1
```

I verified in my database and nothing was update.
Does anyone can tell me what happen ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: THe password bit might need to be wrapped in " ' " like so: `SET password = '<PASSWORD>' `

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function index($email)
{
    $new_password = random_string('alnum', 16);

    $data = array(
        'password' => $new_password
    );

    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->update('CI_TEST', $data);

    $count = $this->db->affected_rows();
    if($count==1)
    {
        return $new_password; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'too many affected rows here';
    }        
}
```

[`$this->db->update();` in Codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)